# Loop to check if cell contains value, then add it to a cell in another sheet

Tags: vba, loops

I'm trying to create a summary chart with the nomimal and max weights for only the Level 1 parts. So my code reads the level 1 column on the first sheet and prints the offset cell value on the second sheet if the level = 1. I'm trying to print the major assembly name, max and nominal weights since these change a lot. This isn't working though. Any ideas?

[image]

Here is my excel file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1GLuBx-ROnhckdza1prZWo3YWM/edit?usp=sharing

Here is my code so far

```
Sub trial()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Group As Range, Mat As Range
    Dim CurCell_1 As Range, CurCell_2 As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Set ws1 = Sheets("Major Assys")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Summary")

    For Each Group In ws1.Range("B4:B200")
        Set CurCell_2 = ws1.Range("B6")
        For Each Mat In ws1.Range("B4:B200")
            Set CurCell_1 = ws1.Cells(Mat.Row, Group.Column)
            If CurCell_1 = 1 Then
            If Not IsEmpty(CurCell_1) Then
                CurCell_2.Value = CurCell_1.Value
                Set CurCell_2 = CurCell_2.Offset(1)
            End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: **This isn't working though**  <-- WHAT isn't working? can you describe what are your expected results, and how the observed results differ? Have you stepped through your code in Debug mode (using F8 to step line by line) to troubleshoot? Does your code raise any errors?  The code looks well-formed, so it should be easy to debug. If you can add some more explanation, you'll have better chance of getting some help.  Cheers.

Comment: I don't see you making use of `ws2` after you set it to "Summary" sheet. Is that what you mean by nothing on Summary is updated? And not sure why double loop for the same range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, this code will work great.

```
Sub MakeSummary()
    Dim oRng1 As Range, oRng2 As Range
    Dim oWS1 As Worksheet, oWS2 As Worksheet, i As Long

    ' Initial cell to check
    Set oWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Major Assys")
    Set oRng1 = oWS1.Range("A4")

    ' Initial cell to store
    Set oWS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set oRng2 = oWS2.Range("B6")

    ' Clear original data on Summary
    i = 0
    Do Until IsEmpty(oRng2.Offset(i, 0))
        oRng2.Offset(i, 0).EntireRow.ClearContents
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ' Look for Level 1's on "Major Assys", then put in to "Summary"
    Do Until IsEmpty(oRng1)
        If oRng1.Value = 1 Then
            oRng2.Value = oRng1.Offset(0, 2).Value ' Description
            oRng2.Offset(0, 1).Value = oRng1.Offset(0, 3).Value ' Nominal
            oRng2.Offset(0, 2).Value = oRng1.Offset(0, 5).Value ' Max
            Set oRng2 = oRng2.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to store
        End If
        Set oRng1 = oRng1.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to check
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    Set oRng1 = Nothing
    Set oWS1 = Nothing
    Set oRng2 = Nothing
    Set oWS2 = Nothing
End Sub
```